# How to Show the Highest Ranks across Different Subtotals in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an app that gives users points for playing games with game having a game_type.  What I want to do is to:

1. subtotal the points based on game
2. determine the users game rank (rank 1 = most points) based on how many points they have for the game_id compared to other users
3. subtotal the points based on game_type
4. determine the users game_type rank (rank 1 = most points) based on how many points they have for the game_type_id compared to other users

Based on the query results above, I'd like to show only the top five points rankings between the game_types and games.

For example, let's say that the calculations are this for the user:

```
game_id = 1, rank 200
game_id = 2, rank 10
game_id = 3, rank 6
game_id = 4, rank 31

game_type_id = 1, rank 500
game_type_id = 2, rank 400
game_type_id = 3, rank 1
game_type_id = 4, rank 7
game_type_id = 5, rank 100
```

Then I would only want to display the rank for games:2, 3, 4 and game_types: 3, 4,5 as these are the top five ranks among the games and game_types for this user.

I thought about creating a game_type and game field for each game_type and game (ie game_1_rank, game_2_rank, game_type_1_rank, etc.) in the user table so I can calculate the points in a background job hourly and then just trying to retrieve the highest ranks from there, but I don't think that's the best approach since new games and game_types are getting added over time.

Therefore, I was thinking the best approach was to do the calculations when the users#show page was loaded and then caching that page (and expiring hourly).

My models look like this:

```
user
  has_many :points

point
  belongs_to :game
  belongs_to :game_type
  belongs_to :user

game
  has_many :points
  has_one :game_type

game_type
  has_many :points
```

I have this code in Users#show to calculate the overall rankings for all of the games and game_types, but I'm not sure how to adjust it so I can access the top ranks in my view (I have no code in my view yet to show the top five ranks for this user and what games/game_types they are for).

```
# calculate ranks for all users for all games in order to find the user's rank
@games = Game.all

@games.each do |game|
  @users_by_game = Point.where(“game_id = ?”, game.id).select("sum(amount) as points, user_id").order("points desc").group("user_id")
  rank = 0
  points = 0

  @users_by_game.each_with_index do |user_by_game, index|           
    if user_by_game.points != points
      points = user_by_game.points
      rank += 1
  end
end

# calculate ranks for all users for all games_types in order to find the user's rank
@game_types = GameType.all   

@game_types.each do |game_type| 
  @users_by_game_type = Point.where(“game_type_id = ?”, game_type.id).select("sum(amount) as points, user_id").order("points desc").group("user_id")
  rank = 0
  points = 0

  @users_by_game_type.each_with_index do |user_by_game_type, index|           
    if user_by_game_type.points != points
      points = user_by_game_type.points
      rank += 1
    end
  end
end
```

What I'm trying to determine is:

1. Is this the best approach for calculating these ranks or is there a more resource efficient or DRY way?
2. If this is the best way, how do I change my code and view to show the highest 5 game/game_type rankings for this @user since the code is now only calculating ranks for all users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce two new tables to store the ranks by game and ranks by game type. Calculate the over-all rank every hour. This way the page load will be much faster. You can use a gem like `whenever` to schedule the rank calculation every hour.

Your current implementation will not scale beyond few hundred users.

```
class User
  has_many :points
  has_many :game_ranks, :order => "rank DESC"
  has_many :game_type_ranks, :order => "rank DESC"

  # schedule this function every hour.
  def self.update_rank
    update_rank_by(Game)
    update_rank_by(GameType)
  end

  def self.top_games(page_size=5)
    game_ranks.includes(:game).limit(page_size)
  end

  def self.top_games_by_type(page_size=5)
    game_type_ranks.includes(:game).limit(page_size)
  end

  def self.update_rank_by klass
    rank_class = (klass.name + "Rank").constantize
    rank_by_col = "#{klass.name.underscore}_id".to_sym        

    rank = total_points = rank_by = 0
    page = 1;page_size=1000
    sql = sum_points_by(rank_by_col)
    while(points= sql.limit(page_size).offset((page-1)*page_size)).present?
      page += 1
      User.trasaction do
        points.each do |point|
          rank_by_col_val = point.send(rank_by_col) 

          # calculate rank
          if ( rank_by != rank_by_col_val)
            rank = total_points = 0
            rank_by = rank_by_col_val
          end

          if point.total_points > total_points
            total_points = point.total_points
            rank +=1
          end

          create_or_update_rank_object(rank_class, rank_by_col, point.user_id, rank_by_col_val, total_points, rank)
        end
      end      
    end    
  end

  def self.sum_points_by(rank_by_col)
    select_sql = "points.user_id, points.#{rank_by_col}, 
                  SUM(points.points) total_points"
    Point.select(select_sql).group(:user_id, rank_by_col).
      order("#{rank_by_col}, total_points DESC")
  end

  def self.create_or_update_rank_object(rank_class, rank_by_col, user_id, rank_by_col_val, total_points, rank)
    ro = rank_class.send(
      "find_or_initialize_by_user_id_and_#{rank_by_col}",
      user_id, rank_by_col_val)
    ro.total_points = total_points           
    ro.rank = rank
    ro.save
  end
end
```

Add a new model to hold ranks and total points for every user and game id

```
class GameTypeRank
  # Add columns total_points and rank 
  belongs_to :game_type
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Add a new model to hold ranks and total points for every user and game type

```
class GameRank
  # Add columns total_points and rank 
  belongs_to :game
  belongs_to :user
end
```

To get the top five games by rank for a user

```
# array of game_id, game_name and game rank
current_user.top_games.map {|r| [r.game.id, r.game.name, r.rank]} 
# array of game_type_id, game_type_name and game rank
current_user.top_games_by_type.map { |r| 
  [r.game_type.id, r.game_type.name, r.rank]
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Harish!  I will try this and let you know!

Comment: Hi Harish, I had a couple of questions just because I wanted to understand what the code was doing.  How does the rank get calculated?  I couldn't figure out how it incremented.  Also, I was wondering if I need to add a .save after the GameRank.find_or_create (or does that statement also save the found record, if one exists).  Thank you!

Comment: I have updated the answer to fix the update issue. I am assuming you are using Postgres database. You can use Window functions in Postgres to calculate the rank.In theory, you can update the rank in `after_save` of `Point` model, but  based on the number of users the cost for calculating the rank might be prohibitive. So it is better to calculate it periodically.

Comment: Here is link to Postgres Window functions http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html

Comment: Oh...I'm using MySQL.  Does it change a lot in MySQL.  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks Harish!  I think that this is very close.  In the code, I changed game.total_points to point.total_points (game was not mentioned so I thought it must be point).  It worked correctly for GameTypeRank where there was only 1 game_type_id in the points table.  However, for the GameRank it did not run as well.  I tested what would happen if there was a tie in points (in which case, I would not expect the rank to increment), as well as multiple game_id's in the points table.  I put the results here: https://gist.github.com/ryanchin/5096235 .  Thank you Harish!

Comment: Thank you Harish!  There still seems to be a bug I can't find.  I had to make a few updates because I was getting error messages.  For some reason the GameTypeRanks table with one game_type_id incremented rank correctly.  However, the GameRanks table with multiple game_id's did not increment correctly.  I commented where I needed to make updates, as well as the trace and table contents here: https://gist.github.com/ryanchin/5097033 .  Thank you for sticking with me Harish!

Comment: The issue was because the `find_in_batches` method ignores the `order` directive. I have changed the code. The new code relies on the `kaminari` gem for pagination.

Comment: Thank you Harish - I put the code in https://s3.amazonaws.com/predict_images/code+1.PNG, but I received a new error about total _points being unknown https://s3.amazonaws.com/predict_images/error.PNG  Thank you!

Comment: It looks like there is a bug in the `kaminari` gem. I have changed the code to remove the `kaminari` dependency.

Comment: Something is not in the correct format, it seems https://s3.amazonaws.com/predict_images/error+2.PNG.  Here's the code https://s3.amazonaws.com/predict_images/code+2.PNG .  I had to delete a "(" in the while...line - there was a mismatch between the () quantities and I was getting an error.  Maybe this caused the issue?

Comment: Line 118 is missing a closing bracket. I have updated the cod.

Comment: Somehow I'm still getting the same error: https://s3.amazonaws.com/predict_images/error+3.PNG.  Here's the code: https://s3.amazonaws.com/predict_images/code+3.PNG

Comment: There was a bug in `116`. I have updated the code. It will work now for sure.

Comment: Thanks Harish.  Getting this error now: https://s3.amazonaws.com/predict_images/error+4a.PNG https://s3.amazonaws.com/predict_images/error+4b.PNG  Here's the code:  https://s3.amazonaws.com/predict_images/code+4.PNG

Comment: I forgot to mention that I added "as" to the select_sql, so it was:  select_sql = "points.user_id, points.#{rank_by_col}, 
                  SUM(points.points) as total_points", but when I look at the error message it still does not seem to have the the summing of total_points in the SQL statement

Comment: I ended up changing the code to make it work, but I did use the concept of making new tables to hold rank and points broken down by combinations of User & Game and User and GameType (instead of creating fields in the User model for each game and game_type) so I'm accepting the answer.  Thank you for the help.